# Running a javascript animation followed by redirecting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I'm fiddling with a fun idea for an offline website I'm currently trying to develop. 
It'll be offline as it's meant to be practice for later study assignments and such.

My problem is the following: I have a javascript function that replaces a PNG with a GIF and *after* the animation it **should** redirect the person to another html I've made.

The source for the JS animation is mainly acquired from here already, but I cannot seem to make it work in the ways I originally intended.

The way it currently works is that I click the png and it'll turn into a gif (no problem there) but what I want is that it runs my js script *and then* redirect to another .html file (url).

The following is my HTML:

```
<object id="syringe">
            <img src="img/syringe.png" height="750" alt="img/syringe.gif" class="center">
            <h2>Click the syringe to inject yourself with a daily dose of puns and jokes</h2>
        </object>
```

The following is the JS:

```
(function($) {

    var getGif = function() {
        var gif = [];
        $('img').each(function() {
            var data = $(this).data('alt');
            gif.push(data);
        });
        return gif;
    }

    var gif = getGif();

    var image = [];

    $.each(gif, function(index) {
        image[index]     = new Image();
        image[index].src = gif[index];
    });

    $('#syringe').on('click', function() {

        var $this   = $(this),
                $index  = $this.index(),

                $img    = $this.children('img'),
                $imgSrc = $img.attr('src'),
                $imgAlt = $img.attr('data-alt'),
                $imgExt = $imgAlt.split('.');

        if($imgExt[1] === 'gif') {
            $img.attr('src', $img.data('alt')).attr('data-alt', $imgSrc);
        } else {
            $img.attr('src', $imgAlt).attr('data-alt', $img.data('alt'));
        }

        $this.toggleClass('play');

    });
})(jQuery);
```

It is to my understanding that I can add a delay and then another function to something in the js - such as the following, which is what I intend to do, however cannot accomplish.

```
[FUNCTION HERE],1000, 
           function(){
              window.location.href=myredirectionuri;
   });
```

And that is my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to have the gif display for a second or two and then redirect, right? If `$this.toggleClass('play');` is the end, then just insert this right after it:

```
setTimeout(() => window.location.href = myredirectionuri, 1000);
```

That'll wait for 1000ms and then redirect to the new page.

Comment: I can't believe this is all I need.. if this works I'll be so happy - however I'm having an issue compressing this to min js because of the open function (() at setTimeout. Is there a way to work around this?

Comment: Ah! I've chosen to just ignore the min js setup due to this. However.. Looking at this it'll just force the redirection after the time duration (1 second) is there a way to force it to just trigger AFTER the animation, rather than to force the animation to stop after X time?

Comment: You mean your environment doesn't support ES2015? Then write out the arrow function the long way instead: `setTimeout(function() { window.location.href = myredirectionuri; }, 1000);`

Comment: What's "the animation"? Is it the switching of the original image for the .gif, or does `.play` trigger something?

Comment: This behaves identically after having tested them. They both cut out the animation and force it to redirect after x time

Comment: Could you explain what the animation you're referring to is?

Comment: Well basically I have a syringe in the form of a PNG that - when clicked - will turn into a GIF. It then does the gif 1 time.. and THEN i want the redirerct

Comment: There is no way to dynamically check to see when a .gif animation has finished. You'll have to hard-code the timeout. You might change your .gif such that it does not restart from the beginning once it's done animating.

Comment: I'll eventually mark this as a solution if nothing more close to a solution arrives, since it's a work around to solve my current problem, but I'll leave it open for further suggestions! I hope this isn't considered bad mannered, as I really appreciate you and others trying to help me!

Answer (score 0):

In the animation script, after it changes to a gif, insert

`setTimeout(function() {
    /* redirect code */
}, /* length of gif in milliseconds */ )`

Comment: The intentions were to allow dynamic gifs to be executed before being redirected, however this doesn't seem possible. Besides - the suggestion made by @certainperformance seems to do exactly this, though differently formatted. - and that works flawlessly - but not dynamically, as I am hoping to achieve.

Comment: Oh ok! Glad you found your answer